# How can I load a content from a PHP Ajax application without the div <div id="output"></div>?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mmenu

I have a PHP Ajax application, and it is working fine, I receive the output query from my secondary php file on `<div id="output"></div>`.

It happens that I am using a mmenu and my output has to be `<li></li>`. I do have this setup on my secondary php file, I receive fine the query and output back from my php on `<li></li>`.

But when I place the `<div id="output"></div>` within the mmenu code it messes up the menu.

I need to have the output dumped on the php page directly without using div as I am using: `<div id="output"></div>`.

I tried `<form id="output"></form>` and it does not work. How can I replace or remove the , and have the pure output on my main PHP page using Ajax?

Comment: if you're receiving `<li>` it should be a child of `<ul>`

Comment: Well, you can always `echo` the tags you need, you are not limited to echoing text.

Comment: The problem that I have is generated by using div. I am looking to use anything on my main PHP page than div. What happens is that when I use div on the main PHP page `<div id="output"></div>` to receive the `<li></li>` content from my secondary PHP page where the query is, this completely messes up the [frebsite mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/). I am trying to display my output within the mmenu. My application can be seen [here](http://www.livebuoy.com/web/) the first item of the menu is what I select, the second is what loads from Ajax. It is currently losing the mmenu format.

Comment: I already tried `<?echo $output;?>` but it does not work.